# data.table in R: Replace a column value with a value from same column after matching two other columns values

Tags: r, replace, data.table, match

I'm not able to get a solution, for my below requirement.
If a data.table(as below) has matching values in Col1 and Col3. Replace Col2 value(old with New-Val).

```
Col1  Col2    Col3
1     old     a
1     old     a
1     New-Val a
```

After manipulating data table should look as below:

```
  Col1  Col2    Col3
   1     New-Val a
   1     New-Val a
   1     New-Val a
```

**Update:**

I've written New-Val for understanding the requirement. However I cannot match this value because it varies for different Col1 and Col3 values. For example as below:

```
Col1  Col2    Col3
1     blank   a
1     blank   a
1     New1    a
2     blank   b
2     new2    b
2     new2    b
```

Likewise the entries are huge. So I ideally want to match Col1 and Col3 and in Col2 it is blank(always) which is to be replaced irrespective of different matched Col1 and Col3 values.

This should be manipulated to:

```
Col1  Col2    Col3
1     New1    a
1     New1    a
1     New1    a
2     new2    b
2     new2    b
2     new2    b
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate in words what are you trying to do and make your example a bit more sophisticated rather than just one value in `Col1` and `Col3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can replace the "blank" values in "Col2" with NA and use `na.locf` to replace the NA with "New" values grouped by "Col1" and "Col3".

```
library(zoo)
dt[Col2=="blank", Col2 := NA]
dt[, Col2 := na.locf(Col2, fromLast=TRUE) ,.(Col1, Col3)]
dt
#   Col1 Col2 Col3
#1:    1 New1    a
#2:    1 New1    a
#3:    1 New1    a
#4:    2 new2    b
#5:    2 new2    b
#6:    2 new2    b
```

---

Or we can do without using any additional package

```
dt[, Col2 := Col2[Col2!='blank'][1L] , .(Col1, Col3)]
```

Comment: Thanks for a reply: I get this error::: Error in `[.data.table`(dt, Col2 == "blank", `:=`(Col2,  : 
  Can't assign to column 'Col2' (type 'factor') a value of type 'logical' (not character, factor, integer or numeric) .   

Col2 is of type Factor, not allowing to replace with NA.

Comment: @Rich It is better to convert `factor` class to `character` class before doing it.  I was using `character` class. i..e `dt[, Col2 := as.character(Col2)][, Col2:= Col2[Col2!="blank"][1L], .(Col1, Col3)]`

Comment: The second solution worked. I will have to yet validate if non of the data got missed as there are total 432,363 entries. 
Can you elaborate what does [1L] do?
Thanks again :)

Comment: @Rich the `[1L]` is just to select the first observation as the "new1", "new2" are unique to a particular group of "col1" and "col3".

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use a binary join combined with `by = .EACHI`- this will work for factors too

```
dt[dt[Col2 != "blank"], Col2 := i.Col2, on = c("Col1", "Col3"), by = .EACHI]
dt
#    Col1 Col2 Col3
# 1:    1 New1    a
# 2:    1 New1    a
# 3:    1 New1    a
# 4:    2 new2    b
# 5:    2 new2    b
# 6:    2 new2    b
```